# Run program in background - Assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

If I've built a program in assembly language, how can I force it to run in background(Without any console)? The program is endless so the console is appearing all the time..

Is there a solution for it, or some interrupt that let me doing this?
Thanks to everyone.

**EDIT: I'm using Tasm Compiler,& my Operating System is windows 7 (32bit)**

Comment: How would you do it for a program you wrote in a different language?  This question isn't really about assembly language, but how to make your system behave differently.

Comment: Search for "terminate and stay resident" if you're programming for DOS.

Comment: Wouldn't you call the main function `WinMain` or `wWinMain`?

Comment: @Michael - I will take a look of this later.. but first, I wan't to see if there's another way to do it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have a console window, you must link your program with `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`
You can refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for the various options.

But that's not really a question related to assembly, because the same applies to any other executable that you create.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to this is that you need to create a Windows application rather than a console application. How to do this is best demonstrated with a minimal example app.

We start by setting the memory model.

```
.386
.model flat
```

Then we include `windows.inc` which gives us access to various constants that we might need in API calls. You probaby won't need this if you aren't doing much with the Windows API.

```
include windows.inc
```

Next we add externs for the functions we want to call. At the very least you'll need to call `ExitProcess`. In this example we're also going to call `MessageBoxA` just so we can see the app do something.

```
extrn ExitProcess : near
extrn MessageBoxA : near
```

Next comes a data segment with a "Hello World" message for the message box.

```
.data
  hello db "Hello World!",0
```

And finally the code. It just calls `MessageBoxA` to display the message, and then `ExitProcess` to exit the application.

```
.code

start:

  push MB_ICONHAND or MB_OKCANCEL
  push offset hello
  push offset hello
  push 0  
  call MessageBoxA        

  push 0
  call ExitProcess

end start
```

Assuming you've saved this code in the file *wintest.asm*, you would then compile it with the following command line:

```
tasm32 /ml wintest.asm
```

The `/ml` option specifies that you want to use case sensitive symbols. Without that, the Windows function calls won't be found by the linker.

If you get an error about not being able to find the *windows.inc* include file, you may also need to include a `/i` option with the path to the Borland include directory.

Finally, you link with the following command line:

```
ilink32 wintest.obj,,,import32.lib,,
```

The `import32.lib` is an import library that links your code to the Windows API.

Assuming everything has compiled and linked successfully, you should now have a Windows app called *wintest.exe*, which when run will pop up a message box, but won't open a console window.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply.

When I'm trying to complie it, i'm getting some error. In the beginning it really gave me the error about the file windows.inc . then I changed the command to this c:\tasm\bin\tasm32 /ml /i c:\tasm\include\windows.inc wintest.asm but it still doesn't works me.. it shows me this Error:
"**FATAL** Invalid argument after /wl".. what I need to do?

Comment: The `/i` parameter should be something like `/ic:\tasm\include` - no space after the `i` and you just need the path to the directory, not the *windows.inc* file.

Comment: I tyried it & now it gaves me the error ** **FATAL** Can't locate file: asm.ASM ** ..

Comment: Are you sure you've got the command line correct? It should be `tasm32 /ml /ic:\tasm\include wintest.asm`.

Comment: Yeah, you right, I wrote it wrong, but still the compiling is not ok.. can I contact with you privately in some way?

Comment: I've created a chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32472/run-program-in-background-assembly-language

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32475/discussion-between-james-holderness-and-aviv)

Comment: The above chat is automatically generated, so hopefully it should work better.

Comment: But I just saw two messages from you? Are you maybe trying to send too much? Like pasting a lot of data into the window?

Comment: Then I don't know. Just continue the discussion here.

Comment: Nevermind, I will try to figure it out alone for now. Thank you Anyway !!

Answer (score 1):

Use [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/) if you are on Linux/Unix.

Comment: Note: Except by "without any console" you meant "build in".

Comment: Thanks, but i'm on windows :)